# Having red line on the if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

problem with the " if (period.Tostring() = "1 year") " wanted to check the database nvarchar and doing a loop since I need to convert it but it give me a red line.

```
string strCommandText4 = "SELECT autoLoanPeriod From AutoLoan WHERE userID= '" + Session["userID"] + "';";
    SqlCommand myCommand4 = new SqlCommand(strCommandText4, myConnection);
    var period = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();


    if (period.ToString() = "1 year")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<= 12; i++)
        {
           string strCommandText5 = "INSERT INTO AutoTrans VALUES(@loanID,@transPeriod,null,@transStatus);";

            SqlCommand myCommand5 = new SqlCommand(strCommandText5, myConnection);
            myCommand5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loanID", Session["@loanID"].ToString());
            myCommand5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transPeriod", numPeriod);
            myCommand5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transStatus", status);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `==` is equality operator, `=` is assignment operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use "==" in If statement . Please try and let me know if it worked.

```
if (period.ToString() == "1 year")
```

You can also try :

> string.Equals(period.ToString(), "1 year");

Comment: already did that but get a green line saying "possible unintended reference comparison, to get a comparison, cast the left hand side to string".

Comment: What type is "period" before you cast it to string?

Comment: Always use string.Equals for comparison. Please mark as answered. Thanks

Comment: var is not really a type but more an auto-type to create the new object with the same type as its input object. 
After you have a value in "period" you could check it via .GetType or compare it with other objects by typeof.
Seems that your issue is solved, but this as some additional information.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
if (period.ToString() == "1 year")
```

or

```
if (period.ToString().Equals("1 year"))
```

to compare strings

Answer (score 1):

As adityaswami89 said, you need to use "==" when checking for equality. In your above code the "=" is attempting to assign the value "1 year" to "period.ToString()" which is an illegal operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the `=` in the if statement as this is trying to `assign` "1 year" to pediod, which can't be done. In your case you want to use the `equality` operators, `==`

```
if (period.ToString() == "1 year")
```

see here for the msdn article on operators;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(v=vs.80).aspx